# How to prevent selecting one column from converting the class from "data.frame" to "numeric"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem I want to draw the frequency histogram of a column using certain filters but then it tells me `Error ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric`.

`ggplot(dataset, aes(x=perdayDiff)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)` works fine but

```
ggplot(subset(dataset$perdayDiff, dataset$symbole == "ASYMO" & dataset$perdayDiff > 0), aes(x=perdayDiff)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
```

returns `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric`

How could I draw a frequency histogram of one column of dataframe using filters on this column and others ? Using ggplot2 if possible.

**Edit** : I could do `ggplot(subset(dataset, dataset$symbole == "AAPL" & dataset$perdayDiff > 0), aes(x=perdayDiff)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)` but does it mean that ggplot2 can't handle `dataframe$x` format ?

Answer (score 1):

You are really abusing `subset()` there. It should be more like

```
subset(dataset, symbole == "ASYMO" & perdayDiff > 0)
```

so, with in the plot

```
ggplot(subset(dataset, symbole == "ASYMO" & perdayDiff > 0), aes(x=perdayDiff)) +  
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
```

At least I think that should work. You did not provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so there's no way to test this solution.

Comment: yes your solution works I edited my post at the same time of your answer but does it mean that ggplot can't handle dataframe$x at all ?

Comment: Your `data=` parameter needs to be a data.frame. `dataframe$x` does not return a data.frame, it returns a vector. Vectors don't have column names so you can't do mapping with aesthetics. You could extract a data.frame with just one column with `dataframe[, "x", drop=F]` but the `$` syntax isn't appropriate here.

Comment: `dataframe[, "x", drop=F]` is a nice trick because you can do operations such as `-dataframe[, "x", drop=F]` which is very useful for my needs. You can't do that working with full dataframes.